# Associating a model with another without nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

Let's say I have a Post model and a Comments model where in the routes file I'm declaring

```
resources :posts
resources :comments
```

NOT

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

Also:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

I can't figure out how to:

1. Create a new form where I can create the Post and its associated Comments at once.

   1a. What does the view look like?

   1b. What goes in what controller?
2. Create a form in a post's show page that adds a comment to that post.

   2a. What does the view look like for the form on the post show page that adds a comment to it?

   2b. What do I add to what controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some documentation. Try the following resources:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2
- The nice [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem
- http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes

After reading them you'll be able to solve all your problems.

Comment: My models are not nested. They are associated AND the routes are independent.